# Is there any solution to run any RTOS on windows/linux virtual machine?

Tags: esp8266, esp32, micropython

I am writing firmware for different boards supporting FreeRTOS, Zephyr, ...

My problem is when I am developing the firmware, I should run the firmware on the "real" device from the beginning and makes it:

- Hard to debug the code, view variables, ...
- Time consuming
- No access to any interactive interface
- Unable to define test automation

I have seen [Renode](https://renode.io/), but my thought is there should be more!

How can I create a virtualized environment for firmware development supporting different RTOS and languages (MicroPython, ...)?

Comment: I am professional embedded software developer. We generally develop a [Hardware Abstraction Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_(software)) (HAL). We develop small software modules to allow for unit test. What you are describing sounds more like Software Integration. Again, we use the HAL, which we developed for unit test, before integrating hardware and software.  Your idea does sounds interesting, though, for my hobby projects; I hope that you get an answer

Comment: Btw, Renode look excellent!! just a pity that it doesn't seem to support ESP32:-(  ST Micro looks worth looking into, though